# How to horizontally align to "block" divs inside a div?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a div with another div inside it, in that div there are 3 `<a>`s. I want the inner div to horizontally align itself in the outer div.

How can i achieve this?

The outer div(Footer_Column) has to have `display: inline_block` and `vertical-align: middle`

***So it looks like this:***

```
-----------------------------
|                           |
|     i'm a link            |
|     i'm a long link       |                         
|     i'm short             |
|                           |
-----------------------------
```

***HTML***

```
<div class="Footer_Column">
    <div class="Footer_Column_Inner">
        <a href="url1.com">i'm a link</a>
        <a href="url2.com">i'm a long link</a>
        <a href="url3.com">i'm short</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

***CSS***

```
.Footer_Column {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 32.7%;
    }
        .Footer_Column_Inner{
            display: inline-block;
        }
        .Footer_Column a {
            display: block;
            font: 13px Trebuchet MS;
            color: #464646;
            text-decoration: none;
        }
```

***Thanks a lot!***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.Footer_Column_Inner {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;  
}
```

no need to specify width

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/piedoom/Jk32y/

I'll explain the CSS:

I added `text align: center` to the parent div to center the item in it, since the child div was an inline-block.

Then, to justify the text left in the child div, I added `text-align: left;`

I added some background coloration to show you how it works, but you would of course remove the color or set it to what you'd need.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, both your and FabioG's answers help! I think i'll go with his since it feels like thats what its for. Thanks anyways though!